# What is causing an Error: System.IO.IOException the process : 1 cannot access file c:\Excel.xlsx because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

This has to be a simple code change, I am asking to user to upload a speadsheet, first time through it is successful, but if I want them to do it again, the second one is unsuccessful

Error: System.IO.IOException the process blazor.server.js:1 cannot access the file c:\temp\Excel.xlsx because it is being used by another process:

Here is the code throwing the error:

```
using var file = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), args.File.Name));
```

here is the rest of code:

```
await args.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(file);
            file.Close();
            var file1 = new FileInfo(file.Name);
```

Comment: use sysinternals handle command to see who has it open

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)

Comment: i know who has it open. me or the process I am running.

Comment: I'm fairly certain of that as well. Ensure that you call the `Dispose` method when one exists or use a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement). While the code you've provided is definitely _minimal_, I'm not sure that it's a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing. Nor is it necessarily representative of what you're doing - the error statement mentions `Blazor`, but you make no mention of it in the tags/post.

Comment: Sharing files in Windows, especially Microsoft Office files, does not work very well.   If you really need a shared database use a database that allows sharing.  You could right click the excel workbook and change property to shared, but that only allows one user to write the file.